# How to create multiple asynchronous java filters?

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, filter, servlet-filters

I'm trying to create a Java application with multiple asynchronous filters, but cannot seem to get them to work well together. I think the main issue is in the run() method I don't know what to do to pass along the request to the next filter in the chain. I've tried `chain.doFilter(request, response)`, but that doesn't seem to work, and there are `dispatch()` and `complete()` APIs available on the `AsyncContext`, but those seem to close out the entire AsyncContext. It seems like there must be another way to get this to work. Below is a snippet of the filter I'm using - the second filter looks almost identical.

Note: I'm adding headers to try and figure out what is getting called.

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
        final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        asyncContext.addListener(new AsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                res.addHeader("S-AST2", "onComplete");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                res.addHeader("S-AST3", "onTimeout");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                res.addHeader("S-AST4", "onError");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                res.addHeader("S-AST0", "onStartAsync");
            }
        });

        asyncContext.start(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                res.addHeader("S-AST1", "before");
                // This doesn't seem to work...
                asyncContext.dispatch();
                // ... or this ...
                asyncContext.complete();
                // ... or this ...
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer.

1) The `chain.doFilter(request, response);` is still required.

2) The reason this was not working is that in each filter and in the servlet I was calling `request.startAsync()`, which started a *new* async process, rather than using an existing one. So if the filter started an async process, and the servlet also started one, it would overwrite/ignore the one started in the filter. To solve this you must check to see if an async process is already started, by calling `request.isAsyncStarted()`, and if it is, rather than starting a new async context, you should get the existing one with `request.getAsyncContext()`. Below is a helper class I created to do this for each servlet and filter, so that I can just call `AsyncHelper.getAsyncContext(request, response)` and it will either retrieve the existing AsyncContext, or create a new one.

```
public class AsyncHelper {
    public static AsyncContext getAsyncContext(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {
        AsyncContext asyncContext = null;
        if (request.isAsyncStarted()) {
            asyncContext = request.getAsyncContext();
        }
        else {
            asyncContext = request.startAsync(request, response);
            asyncContext.setTimeout(2000);
        }
        return asyncContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading the api-docs for `AsyncContext.isAsyncStarted` it looks like this example is susceptible to causing an `IllegalStateException`, depending on what the servlet is doing; between calls to `AsyncContext.isAsyncStarted` and `AsyncContext.getAsyncContext ` another thread may have changed the state of `AsyncContext` by calling `AsyncContext.completed` or `AsyncContext.dispatch`

Answer (score 0):

I had the need to decorate the response, and I did not know whether the underlying servlet was doing async or not, or if it already had completed. On Jetty 9.1.x I solved it by expecting `IllegalStateException`
The following example illustrates how to wrap the response (Using the custom `BufferingHttpServletResponseWrapper` that buffers all that is written to the response) to intercept input so that it can be decorated.

```
     @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
     final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

     // Buffer the output to a string in order to calculate its signature and add the signature to a header before it's sent to the client
     final BufferingHttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new BufferingHttpServletResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

     chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, responseWrapper);

     // This is the only way I can see that will safely let us know if we should treat this as an active async request or not.
     try {
        httpServletRequest.getAsyncContext().addListener(new AsyncListener() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
              LOG.debug("onComplete {}", event);
              decorateResponse(responseWrapper);
           }

           @Override
           public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
              LOG.debug("onTimeout {}", event);
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
              LOG.debug("onError {}", event);
           }

           @Override
           public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
              LOG.debug("onStartAsync {}", event);
              event.getAsyncContext().addListener(this);
           }
        }
        , httpServletRequest, responseWrapper);
        LOG.debug("After chain.doFilter, async was started");
     } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        LOG.debug("Async not active it appears... {}", e.getMessage());
        decorateResponse(responseWrapper);
     }
  }
```